# Error reading UTF-8 file in Java

Tags: java, encoding, internationalization, utf-8

I am trying to read in some sentences from a file that contains unicode characters. It does print out a string but for some reason it messes up the unicode characters

This is the code I have:

```
public static String readSentence(String resourceName) {

    String sentence = null;
    try {
        InputStream refStream = ClassLoader
                .getSystemResourceAsStream(resourceName);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                refStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        sentence = br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot read sentence: " + resourceName);
    }
    return sentence.trim();
}
```

Comment: Hi!!
I am using Eclipse IDE on linux ubuntu 
I was just printing it out by Systen.out and it does print out ok, but it just can not process the unicode characters after that and I have compared it with a string containing the same content (copy pasted from the file) and it says they are not equal.

Comment: hey try this provided you solution there
[check this link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946817/why-does-this-bufferedreader-not-read-in-the-specified-utf-8-format/22062191#22062191

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably in the way that the string is being output.

I suggest that you confirm that you are correctly reading the Unicode characters by doing something like this:

```
for (char c : sentence.toCharArray()) {
    System.err.println("char '" + ch + "' is unicode codepoint " + ((int) ch)));
}
```

and see if the Unicode codepoints are correct for the characters that are being messed up.  If they are correct, then the problem is output side: if not, then input side.

Comment: Thank you I have just tried that and so far they all have the correct unicode codepoints. So what can I do if the problem is on the output side?

Comment: Thaaank you... kept going through different bits of code ends up it was the annoying 'Non-breaking space' character!
Thank you soooooo much

Answer (score 1):

First, you could create the InputStreamReader as

```
new InputStreamReader(refStream, "UTF-8")
```

Also, you should verify if the resource really contains UTF-8 content.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help.
I have checked and it using the getEncoding module it tells me that its UTF8.
I have changed the inputstream and it still is the same.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most annoying reason could be... your IDE settings.

If your IDE default console encoding is something like `latin1` then you'll be struggling very long with different variations of java code but nothing help untill you correctly set some IDE options.

Comment: Hiya.
I have checked because I have had a similar error before. I checked the properties again and it says Inherited from Container (UTF-8)