# Why does this BufferedReader not read in the specified UTF-8 Format?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, bufferedreader

I am scraping a few websites and some of them contain non-Latin Characters and special characters like `“` for quotes rather than `"` and `’` for apostrophes rather than `'`.

*Here's the real curve ball...*

I have the relevant text printed out to the console. Everything encodes fine when I run it in my IDE (Netbeans). But when I run it on my computer `“I Need Your Help”` is printed out as: `ΓÇ£I Need Your HelpΓÇ¥`...

Before anyone says I need to set my `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` Environment Variable to `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` let me say that I have already done that and this is still a problem. Besides, shouldn't my specifying the encoding for the buffered reader to be `"UTF-8"` override that anyway?

Here's some info:

- I'm using the JDK 7 with the target platform as 1.7
- I'm running on a Windows 7 machine for all the machines I'm running this on and experiencing the same problem (some don't have the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` set, but that doesn't seem to make any difference).
- I think the default encoding that it's using is Cp1252...

Here's my code. Let me know whether you need more info. Thanks!

```
/**
 * Using the given url, this method creates and returns the buffered reader for that url
 *
 * @param urlString
 * @return
 * @throws MalformedURLException
 * @throws IOException
 */
public synchronized static BufferedReader getBufferedReader(String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
  URL url = new URL(urlString);
  InputStream is = url.openStream();
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
  return br;
}
```

Comment: I was having an issue where calling a java program direct from hosta: java myprogram   worked, but when I tried to run it remotely ssh me@hosta "java myprogram" it did not work.   It was reading a utf8 input file.  When I added -Dfile.encoding=utf8 it worked!  Thx for that snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities here. As *user1291492* said, it could be that you read the content correctly but the encoding that your terminal uses is different from the one your IDE uses.

The other possibility is that the source data is not in UTF-8. If you're scraping a website, then you should pay attention to what the Website tells you it's using for encoding via the `Content-Type` header, not assume that it's always UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

IDE's output "window" probably has the capacity to understand and print utf-8 characters. The console may not be so advanced

Comment: Can't believe it. That was it. Sorry, I've been having so many problems with this that I thought I'd already tried that. Thanks!

Comment: @kentcdodds It is easier to drive a camel through the eye of a needle than to get Microsoft’s proprietary so-called operating system to play nicely with UTF-8, which is particularly exasperating given that UTF-8 is now the dominant text encoding not merely of Unicode but of all text found on the web worldwide.

Answer (score -1):

```
try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,"UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
      String line="";
      String s ="";
   try 
   {
       line = reader.readLine();
   } 
   catch (IOException e) 
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
      while (line != null) 
      {
       s = s + line;
       s =s+"\n";
       try 
       {
           line = reader.readLine();
       } 
       catch (IOException e) 
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
    tv.setText(""+s);
  }
```